# How to insert a JavaScript variable into razor?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

How can I insert a JavaScript variable into razor? I'm incrementing `counter` by the amount of times the user clicks on `insert-comment` button, and then I have a JavaScript function that adds new input boxes for `Comment`. However, I'm having trouble properly inserting counter as the array index because I'm getting a "the name 'counter' does not exist in the current context" error.

Model:

```
public List<String> Comment {get; set;}
```

---

View:

```
var counter= 0;

jQuery(function($) {
    $('#insert-comment').on("click", function(e) {
        $(this).closest('tr').prev('tr').find('ul')
            .append(
                '<li>' +
                '@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Comment[counter], new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control col-xs-12" } })' +
                '</li>');
    });
    counter++;
});
```

Comment: You can't. Razor is processed on the server before any JS is run. After that, Razor is no longer running. Instead, you probably want to have a local copy of `Comment` that you manipulate. `var comments = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(model.Comment));`

Answer (score 0):

You could copy your variable value in an html element using razor.

This element could be read in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can as the html helper is rendered before any client scripting. I would just append the html for the editor like so.

```
'<li><input type="input" name="Comment[' + counter + ']" class = "form-control col-xs-12"></li>';
```